# How to center sub-item of drop-down menu to parent?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, parent-child, center-align

I am trying to create a drop-down menu in which the children are center-aligned compared to the parent.

I have already tried setting `margin: auto;` or setting `left: -50%; right: -50%` along with other solutions I found online, but nothing seems to work for me.

How can I achieve that?

```css
.header {
  /*background-image: url("../images/top_menu.png");*/
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-origin: border-box;
  height: 68px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  min-width: 160px;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  color: #333333;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul class="drop_menu">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href='#' class="dropbtn">Products</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href='auto_tender_commercial.html'>Link 1</a>
        <a href='fruit_series.html'>Link 2</a>
        <a href='smart_sensors.html'>Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href='#' class="dropbtn">Bar Service Packages</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href='what_is_it.html'>Really long long long long long long long link</a>
        <a href='what_is_it.html'>Link 4</a>
        <a href='leasing_plan.html'>Link 5</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href='event_leasing.html'>Event Leasing</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg60qetq/1/)

Comment: That's because your parent elements are smaller than the children. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: Yes. The parent elements are smaller in width.

Comment: So if the children are centered there would be some space between the parents?

Comment: There would be some space, but it does not really matter, as in the drop-down two parents cannot be selected at the same time.

Comment: Then you should just need text-align: center;

Comment: Sorry, wrong, your child is absolutely positioned, so the parent doesn't know  how wide the child is, and where the center is.

Comment: I have tried text-align: center; :(

Comment: Do the parents have to be flexible width?

Comment: No. They have fixed width.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't look closely ;)

Comment: I played around with it for a little while and I can't figure out how to manage the variable width with only CSS.  It would be quite simple to achieve your desired results with jQuery if that is an option.

Comment: Could you point me to how to achieve that please?

Comment: I added an answer, please check if that is what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: I also added an answer involving jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments it was suggested that jQuery could be an option.

```
$(".dropdown-content").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
       'left' : '50%',
       'margin-left' : $(this).width() / 2 * - 1 + 'px'
    });
});
```

Here is my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pg60qetq/3/

I had to change up the CSS slightly.  I changed the postion from the `DIV` to the `UL`, removed some problematic height and overflow properties.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so your parents are fixed width, the children are bigger than the parent element, also min-width: 150px. The parent is supposed to be centered to the child.

The current problem is that your children are positioned absolute, therefore they do not consume space inside the parent element. So your parent element doesn't know how big the children are, and where the center has to be.

To make sure your parent knows where the center of the children would be, the children have to have some display: setting other than "none", because that makes them take up no space, and they have to be positioned relative. Since we still want the element to be hidden when not hovered, we'll give it a height of 0 and visiblity: hidden;

```
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
}
```

I reduced your test-case to a single dropdown:

https://jsfiddle.net/pg60qetq/1/

This way the parents will take up as much space as they would when hovered though.

Here's the version with all three dropdowns:
https://jsfiddle.net/pg60qetq/2/
Now since the parent is virtually bigger, the elements wrap on a small display.