# How to center the whole dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, submenu

I have a problem with centering my dropdown menu. I've tried everything said on Google and this forum, but nothing helps.The entire submenu is displayed on the left side when opened.

How to put the whole submenu in the middle?

Thank you in advance.

example - https://imgshare.io/image/nVG0u

in jsfiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/em5dj0an

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navbaronder">
<div class="topnav unselectable" id="myTopnav">
    <div id="center1">
   <div id="center2">
       <div class="underline">
       <div id="container2">

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Sales &amp; Marketing</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Administratie &amp; Accounting</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Administratie</a>
<a href="#">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting BE/NL</a>
<a href="#">Financieel Advies</a>
</div>
</div>
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Administratie</a>
<a href="#">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting BE/NL</a>
<a href="#">Financieel Advies</a>
</div>
</div>


           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Logistiek &amp; Transport</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>

           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Drone Fotografie &amp; Videografie</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>

           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Opleidingen &amp; Cursussen</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>


  <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a><!-- golemina na butona --> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
/*********************************************************************************/
/* SERVICES MENU                                                                 */
/*********************************************************************************/


/* menu+submenu*/
#navbaronder {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 155px 0px 0px 0px;  
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  outline: 0; 
}

/*********************************************************************************/
/* UNSELECTABLE                                                                  */
/*********************************************************************************/

.unselectable {           
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}

img::selection {          
    background: transparent;

}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* ANIMATING LINK UNDERLINES                               */
/*********************************************************************************/

/* pod4ertavane na pada6tite butoni*/
.underline > a, button  {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: white;
}

.underline > a, button:hover {
  color: white;
}

.underline > a, button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.underline > a, button:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* DROP DOWN RESPONSIVE MENU                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/

body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #dddddd;  

}
#center1 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;

}

#center2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}



.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 8px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px; 
}

.topnav .icon {  
  display: none;
  color:#2654BA;
}

.dropdown {    
  float: left; 
  overflow: hidden;

}


.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;   
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;   
  padding: 6px 20px; 
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  /*  display: inline-block; ???????????? */
    /*padding: 5px 60px 0px 0px;   */

}

            .dropdown-content { 
  display: none;   
  position: fixed; 
  background-color: #f9f9f9;    
  min-width: 120px;      
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;   

}



            .dropdown-content a {   
  float: none;    
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 8px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  background-color:#f1f1f1; 

}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn { 
  background-color:transparent; 
  color: #2651AB; 

}

.dropdown-content a:hover { 
  background-color: #ddd; 
  color: black;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
  display:block;

}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are willing to use jquery for this, there is an answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681972/how-to-center-sub-item-of-drop-down-menu-to-parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

changed position of dropdown from `fixed` to `absolute`!

removed `overflow:hidden` from navbar and `.dropdown`  class.

hope this what you are looking for.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/*********************************************************************************/
/* SERVICES MENU                                                                 */
/*********************************************************************************/


/* menu+submenu*/
#navbaronder {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  outline: 0; 
}

/*********************************************************************************/
/* UNSELECTABLE                                                                  */
/*********************************************************************************/

.unselectable {           
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}

img::selection {          
    background: transparent;

}
 

/*********************************************************************************/
/* ANIMATING LINK UNDERLINES        pod4ertavane na menuto                       */
/*********************************************************************************/

/* pod4ertavane na pada6tite butoni*/
.underline > a, button  {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: white;
}

.underline > a, button:hover {
  color: white;
}

.underline > a, button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.underline > a, button:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* DROP DOWN RESPONSIVE MENU                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/

body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  background-color: #dddddd;  
  
}
#center1 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    
}

#center2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}



.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 8px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px; 
}

.topnav .icon {  
  display: none;
  color:#2654BA;
}

.dropdown {    
  float: left; 
 position:relative;

}


.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;   
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;   
  padding: 6px 20px; 
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  /*  display: inline-block; ???????????? */
    /*padding: 5px 60px 0px 0px;   */
  
}

            .dropdown-content { 
  display: none;   
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #f9f9f9;    
  min-width: 120px;      
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;   

}



            .dropdown-content a {   
  float: none;    
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 8px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  background-color:#f1f1f1; 

}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn { 
  background-color:transparent; 
  color: #2651AB; 
 
}

.dropdown-content a:hover { 
  background-color: #ddd; 
  color: black;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
  display:block;

}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<div id="navbaronder">
<div class="topnav unselectable" id="myTopnav">
    <div id="center1">
   <div id="center2">
       <div class="underline">
       <div id="container2">
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Sales &amp; Marketing</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Administratie &amp; Accounting</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Administratie</a>
<a href="#">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting BE/NL</a>
<a href="#">Financieel Advies</a>
</div>
</div>
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Administratie</a>
<a href="#">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting BE/NL</a>
<a href="#">Financieel Advies</a>
</div>
</div>
           
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Logistiek &amp; Transport</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
           
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Drone Fotografie &amp; Videografie</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
           
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Opleidingen &amp; Cursussen</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
          
  
  <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a><!-- golemina na butona --> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working perfect.Now the whole submenu is aligned.Thank you very much!

Comment: May I ask if you know how the text can be reduced in proportion by reducing the screen of the browser to -for example- 600 pixels. Then the "hamburger" menu icon should appear.

The problem is that when the browser shrinks to those pixels, the links are stacked one below the other. I want the text to be reduced proportionally to 600px.

Comment: @Vall you mean a smaller text on  smaller screens?

Comment: I mean smaller text.
If I set the text to shrink with @media it will be variable font size.I wan text to be responsive font size to 600px. and then the "hamburger" icon to be shown if its possibe.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be he perfect answer but it will solve the issue.

```
.dropdown{
    float: left;
    /* overflow: hidden; <- remove this */
    position: relative;
}
```

```
.dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/*********************************************************************************/
/* SERVICES MENU                                                                 */
/*********************************************************************************/


/* menu+submenu*/
#navbaronder {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 155px 0px 0px 0px;  
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  outline: 0; 
}

/*********************************************************************************/
/* UNSELECTABLE                                                                  */
/*********************************************************************************/

.unselectable {           
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}

img::selection {          
    background: transparent;

}
 

/*********************************************************************************/
/* ANIMATING LINK UNDERLINES        pod4ertavane na menuto                       */
/*********************************************************************************/

/* pod4ertavane na pada6tite butoni*/
.underline > a, button  {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: white;
}

.underline > a, button:hover {
  color: white;
}

.underline > a, button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.underline > a, button:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* DROP DOWN RESPONSIVE MENU                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/

body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  background-color: #dddddd;  
  
}
#center1 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    
}

#center2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}



.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 8px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px; 
}

.topnav .icon {  
  display: none;
  color:#2654BA;
}

.dropdown {    
  float: left; 
 position: relative;

}


.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;   
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;   
  padding: 6px 20px; 
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  /*  display: inline-block; ???????????? */
    /*padding: 5px 60px 0px 0px;   */
  
}

            .dropdown-content { 
  display: none;   
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;    
  min-width: 120px;      
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;   

}



            .dropdown-content a {   
  float: none;    
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 8px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  background-color:#f1f1f1; 

}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn { 
  background-color:transparent; 
  color: #2651AB; 
 
}

.dropdown-content a:hover { 
  background-color: #ddd; 
  color: black;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
  display:block;

}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<div id="navbaronder">
<div class="topnav unselectable" id="myTopnav">
    <div id="center1">
   <div id="center2">
       <div class="underline">
       <div id="container2">
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Sales &amp; Marketing</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Administratie &amp; Accounting</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Administratie</a>
<a href="#">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting BE/NL</a>
<a href="#">Financieel Advies</a>
</div>
</div>
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Administratie</a>
<a href="#">Boekhouding &amp; Accounting BE/NL</a>
<a href="#">Financieel Advies</a>
</div>
</div>
           
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Logistiek &amp; Transport</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
           
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Drone Fotografie &amp; Videografie</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
           
           <div class="dropdown"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
           
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Opleidingen &amp; Cursussen</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
          
  
  <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a><!-- golemina na butona --> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I change -- position: fixed;  to --- position: absolute;  the whole submenu disappears.

Comment: @Vall remove overflow hidden from `topnav` class also

Comment: If I removed  overflow: hidden;  from   .topnav   the submenu remains permanently visible, but centered.

Comment: @Vall I have added a working snippet. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your dropdown structure like this

```
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
<a href="#">Marketing</a>
</div>
</div>
```

and it should work

Comment: Your code also solves my problem.
The difference with the above code of "abdel" is only when the screen is small.
In the above code, the alignment remains on the left and yours aligns in the middle, but this is a very good solution too.

Thank you very much.